# Cobalt Error: Accessing Document in Doc Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

From searching, cobalt has something to do with SOAP and data transfer of the documents.  I have gotten a cobalt error twice on a document that prevents it from being opened, downloaded, and viewed. I am not sure what is causing this issue, or how to address it.

The only solution at this point has been to delete the file and upload it again.  Does anyone have any insights or suggestions for this issue?

As a note, this is SharePoint online.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a very large document, that is causing this issue?

Comment: @BennySkogberg The file in question is at 4486 KB.  Would this be nearing a limit?

Comment: not at all. File size limit is 2GB. https://support.office.com/en-au/article/SharePoint-Online-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498

Comment: @BennySkogberg I thought I remembered the limit being that high, thanks for the reference.